# Find an element by two texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm basically trying to get the object of an HTML element that contains two specifics strings.

I made the following example that contains two `divs` and are each called `case`. So I'd like to get its object using the values that the `p` tags that it contains :

```
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Alford</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>John</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
```

What I already tried is using jQuery using the `contains()` method :
`$( ".case:contains('Joseph')" );` but it of course returns both objects where the namer "Joseph" is contained.

What I'd like to get is the ONLY the "Joseph Alford" HTML object.

Comment: If using `Joseph` got you both, why not use use the last name `Quigley`? eg. `contains() method : $( ".case:contains('Quigley')" );`

Comment: Yes you're right. But what if we have another person called "John Quigley" ? I need to be more precise on my post, sorry. I edit

Comment: So do you want both `div` elements or just the first match? It's not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What i'm trying to get is only one object, the "Joseph Alford" one.

Comment: Again though, can you be more clear? What if the Joseph Alford is the second one in the list? Do you always want that one or the first match found?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I always want that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use another `:contains` selector:

```js
$( ".case:contains('Joseph'):contains('Alford')" ).css({"border": "1em solid chartreuse"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Alford</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>John</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the element you want could be in any position, you'll first have to get all the `case:contains("Joseph")` elements and then loop over them to see if the element then contains the correct last name.

```js
// Get all the case elements that contain "Joseph" and loop over them
$(".case:contains('Joseph')").each(function(idx,el){
  // Check each element to see if "Alford" is contained within it as well
  if(el.textContent.indexOf("Alford") > -1){
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Alford</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>John</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally made what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript:

```js
function findElWithName(name, selector) {
  const regEx = RegExp(name.split(" ").join("\\s+"));
  for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
    if (regEx.test(el.textContent)) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}

findElWithName("Joseph Alford", ".case").style.outline = "1px solid red";
```

```html
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Alford</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>Joseph</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
<div class="case">
    <p>John</p>
    <p>Quigley</p>
</div>
```

or oneliner:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".case")].filter(e => e.textContent.match(/Joseph\s+Alford/))
```